# Laravel Nova Conditional Validation : required_if + exists rule

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation, laravel-nova

I'm trying to validate `'parent_code'` attr regarding `'level'` field value

Here is what i'm trying to achieve :

`'parent_code'` is **only required** when `'level'` is != 0 (This part works fine)

and when it's set, it **must also** exists in table `'products'` (`'product_code'` : the column name that will be used)

My current code (doesn't work properly)

Product resource class

```
public function fields(Request $request) {
        return [
            ID::make()->sortable(),

            Text::make('Product code', 'product_code')
                ->rules('required')
                ->creationRules('unique:products,product_code')
                ->updateRules('unique:products,product_code,{{resourceId}}')->hideFromIndex(),


            Text::make('Product short name', 'product_short_name')->onlyOnForms(), 


            Textarea::make('Product name', 'product_name')
                ->rules('required')
                ->sortable()
                ->onlyOnForms(),

            Text::make('Parent code', 'parent_code')
                ->rules(['required_if:level,2,4,6', 'exists:products,product_code'])
                ->hideFromIndex(), 

            Select::make('Level', 'level')->options([
                '0' => 'Sector level',
                '2' => 'H2',
                '4' => 'H4',
                '6' => 'H6',
            ])->rules('required')->sortable(),    

        ];
}
```

Create Product Form

[image: Create product form]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you need to apply the `exists` rule only if the `required if` is satisfied?

Comment: Exactly, only when required if is satisfied

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The proper way would have been to use the `sometimes()` method on the validator instance, but you can't access it from Laravel Nova rules.

You can just define the `rules` as a closure that recieves the current incoming request and check the value to dinamically build the rules array:

**Laravel Collections solution**

```php
Text::make('Parent code', 'parent_code')
    ->hideFromIndex()
    ->rules(function ($request) {
        // You could also use "->when(...)" instead of "->unless(...)"
        // and invert the condition (first argument)
        return collect(['required_if:level,2,4,6'])
            ->unless($request->level === 0, function ($rules) {
                return $rules->push('exists:products,product_code');
            })
            ->toArray();
    }),
```

The logic without using collections is the same, just use basic if statements to dynamically add conditions:

**Plain PHP Arrays Solution**

```php
Text::make('Parent code', 'parent_code')
    ->hideFromIndex()
    ->rules(function ($request) {
        return [
            'required_if:level,2,4,6',
            ($request->level !== 0) ? 'exists:products,product_code' : '',
        ];
    }),
```

or (variant):

```php
Text::make('Parent code', 'parent_code')
    ->hideFromIndex()
    ->rules(function ($request) {
        $rules = ['required_if:level,2,4,6'];

        if ($request->level !== 0) {
            $rules[] = 'exists:products,product_code';
        }

        return $rules;
    }),
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and your time, now i'm getting  "Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validateRequiredIf:level,2,4,6 does not exist."

Comment: Which nova version are you using? Also, try to chain `->toArray();` method after the `unless` call.

Comment: i'm using v2.8.0

Comment: This works perfectly fine when using $request->level === '0'. Thank you

Comment: Since you are using Laravel I proposed you a solution with collections, but if you are more comfortable with normal php arrays just let me know and I'll add a variant of this solution without collections as well.

Comment: Yes please, this would be great.